# PHP Script unlinks files interactively in browser, but not as cPanel cron job

Tags: php, linux, cron, cpanel

The following execution syntax actually runs in cron job:

`/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/pbjwbh0mgv9o/public_html/buildlistings.php`

Yet I get the following in my error_log:

> [05-May-2018 21:53:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  unlink(property_a.xml): No such file or directory in /home/pbjwbh0mgv9o/public_html/buildlistings.php on line 63
>
> [05-May-2018 21:53:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  unlink(property_map.xml): No such file or directory in /home/pbjwbh0mgv9o/public_html/buildlistings.php on line 215

Once again the following part of script executes perfectly in browser, and attached below is screenshot of directory:

```
unlink('property_a.csv');
unlink('property_a.xml');
unlink('property_map.xml');
```

[image: Directory snapshot]

Am I formatting the cron job command incorrectly, or missing something within my script related to Linux?

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the script via the web server, the CWD (current working directory) is what you expect.

When cron executes that job, it's not happening from the same location. You need to make sure it calls `cd` to change to wherever you expect the files to be.

Edit:
Here's an example for your cron job:

`cd /home/pbjwbh0mgv9o/public_html && /usr/local/bin/php -q buildlistings.php`